# SSRS - Managing Folder, GET AllowedActions Method Returns 404

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I'm using `SQL Server 2017 Reporting Service` and I see that something is wrong with my **permissions**. I'm in the Administrator group in the SSRS machine, I can manage most of the folders in the SSRS browser web app but I can't manage some of them...

For example,

- I newly created a folder called CWB, I can manage the CWB folder's own permissions
- When I navigate into the CWB folder, I can't manage folders or permissions inside of the CWB folder

Then I realized that when I clicked to manage button on the folder, SSRS sent `GET` request called `AllowedActions` and the request returned with users permitted actions, so I examined the body of that request and found this,

For the CWB folder, I get the permissions successfully `AllowedActions` method returns **Status: (200)**,

[image: GET AllowedActions Returns 200]

But when I navigate into the CWB folder and try to manage another folder inside of the CWB folder, `AllowedActions` method returns **Status: (404)** as seen below,

[image]

And the error message says,

### **An error has occurred.**  Something went wrong. Please try again later.

Other group members of the Administrator can manage/edit the same folder/folders except me. I will very much appreciate it if anyone helps me to fix this issue.

Thank you for reading my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://jasonjonesdata.blogspot.com/2017/12/power-bi-report-server-bug-causes-menus.html) article,

Encoding should be the problem. So try and look at your browser language. Changing your broweser language to English will fix your problem.